# ZeroMQ (cppzmq) subscriber skips first message

Tags: c++, zeromq

I'm trying to use [ZMQ](http://zeromq.org) with the [CPPZMQ](http://zeromq.org/topics:cppzmq) C++ wrapper, as it seems it is the one suggested in [C++ Bindings](http://zeromq.org/bindings:cpp).

The client/server (REQ/REP) seems to work fine.
When trying to implement a publish/subscribe pair of programs, it looks like the first message is lost in the subscriber. Why?

publisher.cpp:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t publisher(context, ZMQ_PUB);
    publisher.bind("tcp://*:5555");

    for(int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
        zmq::message_t env1(1);
        memcpy(env1.data(), "A", 1);
        std::string msg1_str = (boost::format("Hello-%i") % (n + 1)).str();
        zmq::message_t msg1(msg1_str.size());
        memcpy(msg1.data(), msg1_str.c_str(), msg1_str.size());
        std::cout << "Sending '" << msg1_str << "' on topic A" << std::endl;
        publisher.send(env1, ZMQ_SNDMORE);
        publisher.send(msg1);

        zmq::message_t env2(1);
        memcpy(env2.data(), "B", 1);
        std::string msg2_str = (boost::format("World-%i") % (n + 1)).str();
        zmq::message_t msg2(msg2_str.size());
        memcpy(msg2.data(), msg2_str.c_str(), msg2_str.size());
        std::cout << "Sending '" << msg2_str << "' on topic B" << std::endl;
        publisher.send(env2, ZMQ_SNDMORE);
        publisher.send(msg2);

        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

subscriber.cpp:

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t subscriber(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
    subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "B", 1);

    while(true)
    {
        zmq::message_t env;
        subscriber.recv(&env);
        std::string env_str = std::string(static_cast<char*>(env.data()), env.size());
        std::cout << "Received envelope '" << env_str << "'" << std::endl;

        zmq::message_t msg;
        subscriber.recv(&msg);
        std::string msg_str = std::string(static_cast<char*>(msg.data()), msg.size());
        std::cout << "Received '" << msg_str << "'" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
$ ./publisher
Sending 'Hello-1' on topic A
Sending 'World-1' on topic B
Sending 'Hello-2' on topic A
Sending 'World-2' on topic B
Sending 'Hello-3' on topic A
Sending 'World-3' on topic B

$ ./subscriber
Received envelope 'B'
Received 'World-2'
Received envelope 'B'
Received 'World-3'
```

(note: subscriber is executed before executing publisher)

**Bonus question:** By the way, is it my impression or this C++ wrapper it is quite low level? I see no direct support for std::string and the code to transmit a simple string looks quite verbose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer in [the ZeroMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all):

> There is one more important thing to know about PUB-SUB sockets: you
>   do not know precisely when a subscriber starts to get messages. Even
>   if you start a subscriber, wait a while, and then start the publisher,
>   **the subscriber will always miss the first messages that the publisher**
>   **sends**. This is because as the subscriber connects to the publisher
>   (something that takes a small but non-zero time), the publisher may
>   already be sending messages out.
>
> This "slow joiner" symptom hits enough people often enough that we're
>   going to explain it in detail. Remember that ZeroMQ does asynchronous
>   I/O, i.e., in the background. Say you have two nodes doing this, in
>   this order:
>
> Subscriber connects to an endpoint and receives and counts messages.
>   Publisher binds to an endpoint and immediately sends 1,000 messages.
>   Then the subscriber will most likely not receive anything. You'll
>   blink, check that you set a correct filter and try again, and the
>   subscriber will still not receive anything.
>
> Making a TCP connection involves to and from handshaking that takes
>   several milliseconds depending on your network and the number of hops
>   between peers. In that time, ZeroMQ can send many messages. For sake
>   of argument assume it takes 5 msecs to establish a connection, and
>   that same link can handle 1M messages per second. During the 5 msecs
>   that the subscriber is connecting to the publisher, it takes the
>   publisher only 1 msec to send out those 1K messages.
>
> In [Chapter 2 - Sockets and Patterns](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#sockets-and-patterns) we'll explain how to synchronize a
>   publisher and subscribers so that you don't start to publish data
>   until the subscribers really are connected and ready. There is a
>   simple and stupid way to delay the publisher, which is to sleep. Don't
>   do this in a real application, though, because it is extremely fragile
>   as well as inelegant and slow. Use sleeps to prove to yourself what's
>   happening, and then wait for [Chapter 2 - Sockets and Patterns](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#sockets-and-patterns) to see
>   how to do this right.
>
> The alternative to synchronization is to simply assume that the
>   published data stream is infinite and has no start and no end. One
>   also assumes that the subscriber doesn't care what transpired before
>   it started up. This is how we built our weather client example.
>
> So the client subscribes to its chosen zip code and collects 100
>   updates for that zip code. That means about ten million updates from
>   the server, if zip codes are randomly distributed. You can start the
>   client, and then the server, and the client will keep working. You can
>   stop and restart the server as often as you like, and the client will
>   keep working. When the client has collected its hundred updates, it
>   calculates the average, prints it, and exits.

Comment: thanks. so we may need coordination: http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Node-Coordination

Answer (score 1):

### Bonus answer:

ZeroMQ has been designed for high-performance messaging / signalling and as such has some design-maxims, around which the core-parts have been developed.

Zero-Copy and Zero-Sharing are those more well-known, Zero-(almost)-Latency might be ( a bit ) provocative one, and a Zero-Warranty is perhaps a one, you would like least to hear about.

Yes, ZeroMQ does not strive to provide any explicit warranty to be assumed ( naturally, due to many reasons common in worlds of distributed-systems ), but **yet it gives you one warranty of this kind** -- any message is either delivered atomically ( i.e. complete, error-free ) -- or not at all ( so one will indeed never have to pay any extra costs, associated with detecting and discarding any runts and/or broken message-payloads ).

So may rather forget to worry about any packets undelivered, and what if these were delivered etc etc. You simply get as much as possible, and the rest is not under your influence ( "Late-joiner" cases could be considered as a boundary, where ( if ) one were in such a position to be able to enforce more time for "slow-joiner"(s), then none such observable difference would change the code-design, so rather try to design distributed-systems to be robust against ( principally ) possible undelivered signals / messages ).

### API? Wrapper...

If interested in this level-of-detail, would recommend to read API, since some v2.x, so that one may better realise all the thoughts, that were put behind the strive for maximum performance ( Zero-Copy motivated set of message-preparation steps, advanced API-calls for messages, that would get re-sent, memory-leaks prevention, advanced IO-thread-Pool maps for increased IO-throughput / reduced latency / relative-prioritisations et al ).

After this, one may review how well ( or how poor ) any respective non-native language-binding ( wrapper ) did reflect these initial design-efforts into cross-ported programming environment.

Most of such efforts have got into troubles right with finding a reasonable balance between a user-programming comfort, the target programming-environment expressivity constraints and minimising sins of leaking memory or compromised quality of API-binding/wrapper.

It is fair to note, that designing a non-native language binding is one of a few most challenging tasks. Thus one ought bear with such brave teams who decided to step into this territory ( and sometimes failed to mirror all the native-API strengths without degraded performance and/or clarity of original intents -- needless to add, that many native-API features might even get excluded from becoming accessible from environments, that cannot provide seamless integration within the scope of such non-native language expressivity, so care is to be taken once evaluating an API-binding/wrapper ( and original native-API will always help to get to the roots of ZeroMQ original powers ) - anyway - in most corner cases, one may try to inline in critical sections ).